# Table of totals for the last 12 months, both by month and running

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to have a table that contains 12 rows, one for each of the last 12 months, and two additional columns:

- That month's (and only that month's) total spend
- Total spend to date, since the beginning of time

The table could look like:

```
Month   MonthTotal      RunningTotal
Apr 16  0               6710
May 16  0               6710
Jun 16  2000            8710
Jul 16  0               8710
Aug 16  0               8710
Sep 16  0               8710
Oct 16  1000            9710
Nov 16  0               9710
Dec 16  0               9710
Jan 17  500             10210
Feb 17  0               10210
Mar 17  0               10210
```

I'm almost there but I'm hitting an issue when I have months with no purchases in them - that column is being output as null. Here's my current query:

```
with Y(n) as
(
    select 0
    union all
    select n + 1 
    from Y
    where n < 11
)

select
    convert(varchar, M.Month) + '/' + convert(varchar, M.Year % 100) as Month,
    isnull(sum(A.Value), 0) as MonthAssetValue,
    sum(A.Value) over (order by A.DateAquired rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as TotalAssetValue

from (
    select
        datepart(year, dateadd(month, -n, getdate())) as [Year],
        datepart(month, dateadd(month, -n, getdate())) as [Month]

    from
        Y
) M

left outer join Asset A
    on (datepart(year, A.DateAquired) = M.Year and datepart(month, A.DateAquired) = M.Month)


group by
    M.Year,
    M.Month,
    A.DateAquired,
    A.Value

order by
    M.Year,
    M.Month
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**Edit:**

This is the output I currently get:

```
Month   MonthTotal      RunningTotal
Apr 16  0               null            
May 16  0               null            
Jun 16  2000            8710
Jul 16  0               null            
Aug 16  0               null            
Sep 16  0               null            
Oct 16  1000            9710
Nov 16  0               null            
Dec 16  0               null            
Jan 17  500             10210
Feb 17  0               null            
Mar 17  0               null
```

Comment: Can you provide input table?

Comment: Can you show your expected output and actual expected ouput

Comment: cant you just put isnull(<purchasecolumn>, 0) for the purchase colunm

Comment: Question updated with my current output.

Comment: Whats SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling windowing function

```
SELECT Month, MonthTotal, [Sum 12 Months] = SUM(MonthTotal) OVER (ORDER BY [Month] ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `group by`.  It should only have the year and the month:

```
group by M.Year, M.Month
```

In addition, don't use `varchar()` without a length.  And, I think there is a syntax error in the windows function call.  You need to mix the aggregation and window functions.

I would write the query as:

```
with Y(n) as (
      select 0
      union all
      select n + 1 
      from Y
      where n < 11
     )
select left(m.mmm, 3) + '/' + right(yyyymm.yyyy, 2) as mmmyy,
       coalesce(sum(A.Value), 0) as MonthAssetValue,
       sum(coalesce(sum(A.Value), 0)) over (order by min(dte)) as TotalAssetValue
from (select datename(year, dateadd(month, -n, getdate())) as yyyy,
             datename(month, dateadd(month, -n, getdate())) as mmm,
             dateadd(month, -n, getdate()) as dte
      from Y
     ) yyyymm left outer join
     Asset A
     on datename(year, A.DateAquired) = yyyymm.yyyy and
        datename(month, A.DateAquired) = yyyymm.mmm
group by yyyymm.yyyy, yyyymm.mmm
order by min(dte);
```

Actually, to be honest, I would represent the year/month as YYYY-MM, but I kept your format.

Comment: This half works. However, the running total only starts becoming non-null after the first non-zero month in the last 12 months - it's not considering months that aren't in the output.

Comment: @James . . . That's about 99% working.  You only need a `coalesce()` to get a `0` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

Try replace  sum(A.Value) as MonthAssetValue,
    sum(A.Value) over (order by A.DateAquired) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as TotalAssetValue

**with below**

SUM(COALESCE(A.Value, 0)) as MonthAssetValue,

SUM(COALESCE(A.Value, 0))  over (order by A.DateAquired) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as TotalAssetValue

Comment: This just sets all my null columns to 0, which is not the desired output.